# Is there a word like Gaia, but to refer to the people of the world?

Tags: reference-request, terminology

Is there a word like *Gaia*, but to refer to the people of the world rather than the entire biosphere?

It might be the "Human Race" or the "Human Species", but I am thinking in conceptual terms or identity. Tribes almost always have a term meaning "the people". Humans need to start thinking about the survival of the human species as a goal. We would probably need a term other than "human species" as part of the concept.

Maybe I'll try to make one up, but it would be far better if I could use an existing word with useful connotations. T'anks, M

Comment: "Humanity" may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I will take some of these comments down, but with due respect, you may be assuming that the Subject stays the same throughout history. But we are dealing with a very reduced Subject today:  his Android device (Object) and such like, leads him around by the nose.

Comment: Gaia was the ancient Greek goddess of the Earth. Since there was no goddess of the people there is no such word like it. The Greek word for humanity was [ánthrōpos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%84%CE%BD%CE%B8%CF%81%CF%89%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%82).

Comment: @Gordon One may hope(pray) for a [short and sweet finale](https://www.express.co.uk/news/science/1167504/NASA-Elon-Musk-latest-Asteroid-news-Twitter-god-of-chaos-Apophis-2029-earth-approach-Space).

Comment: @Rusi thank you. I clicked on the link. Lol.

Comment: I think Frank's term "Humanity" might do. Very good call that one. I hate making up words, but sometimes I have to.